# LightZAP v2.54 (silent update2) (Lightbox custom plugin) auto start when page loads with tag name (#img1)

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox

I have `LightZAP` plugin which is an alternative to `Lightbox` running on my website. I want to run it (pop out an image gallery with a specific image) when page loads using: `index.html#img1` link if thats possible.

I have seen similar scripts for `lightbox v2`, did try to customize them to use on `LightZAP` but couldn't run it. Thats the example in here: http://frankleng.me/2010/07/21/drupal-tip-lightbox-pop-up-on-page-load/

Any help would be much appreciated.

Code for LightZAP:

```
` /* LightZAP v2.54 (silent update2)
by Szalai Mihaly - http://dragonzap.szunyi.com
original by Lokesh Dhakar (lightbox) - http://lokeshdhakar.com

For more information, visit:
http://dragonzap.szunyi.com/index.php?e=page&al=lightzap&l=en

Licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 License - http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/
- free for use in both personal and commercial projects
- attribution requires leaving author name, author link, and the license info intact

Thanks
- Scott Upton(uptonic.com), Peter-Paul Koch(quirksmode.com), and Thomas Fuchs(mir.aculo.us) for ideas, libs,       and snippets.
- Artemy Tregubenko (arty.name) for cleanup and help in updating to latest proto-aculous in v2.05.
- Szalai Mihaly (dragonzap.szunyi.com), automatic image resize for screen, fullscreen viewer,  print button,     download button, like button and new design.*/

var imgNotFound,
//----- Options --------
imagetext   = "",   //"Image "
oftext      = " / ",//" of "
bytext      = "",   //"by"
notfoundtext    = "Image not found",
print       = false,
download    = true,
like        = true;
buy         = true;
 //----------------------

var $lightzap, $container, $image, $lbContainer;
var windowWidth, windowHeight, originalWidth, originalHeight, album = [], currentImageIndex = 0, isfull =     false, marginWidth = -1, marginHeight = -1;
var pfx = ["webkit", "moz", "ms", "o", ""];

function getElementsByClassName(element, className) {
if (element.getElementsByClassName)
    return element.getElementsByClassName(className);
else
    return document.querySelectorAll('.' + className);
};

 function lzInit()
{
    //Set links
var _ref = document.links, i = _ref.length;
while (i--)
{
    var a = _ref[i];
    if (a.getAttribute("data-lightzap") != null)
        a.onclick = function () {return lzStart(this);};
}

//FullScreen
var pfx0 = ["IsFullScreen", "FullScreen"], pfx1 = ["CancelFullScreen", "RequestFullScreen"];
var k, m, t = "undefined", p = 0;
while (p < pfx.length && !document[m])
{
    k = 0;
    while (k < pfx0.length)
    {
        m = pfx0[k];
        if (pfx[p] == "")
        {
            m = m.substr(0, 1).toLowerCase() + m.substr(1);
            pfx1[0] = pfx1[0].substr(0, 1).toLowerCase() + pfx1[0].substr(1);
            pfx1[1] = pfx1[1].substr(0, 1).toLowerCase() + pfx1[1].substr(1);
        }
        m = pfx[p] + m;
        t = typeof document[m];
        if (t != "undefined")
        {
            pfx = [pfx[p] + pfx1[0], pfx[p] + pfx1[1], m];
            p = 2;
            break;
        }
        k++;
    }
    p++;
}

//Build lightzap
$lightzap = document.createElement("div");
$lightzap.id = "lightzap";
$lightzap.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild($lightzap);

var tmp = document.createElement("div");
tmp.className = "lz-bg";
tmp.onclick = lzEnd;
$lightzap.appendChild(tmp);

$container = document.createElement("div");
$container.className = "lz-container";
$container.style.display = 'none';
$lightzap.appendChild($container);

tmp = document.createElement("div");
tmp.className = "lz-loader";
$container.appendChild(tmp);

$image = document.createElement("img");
$image.className = "lz-image";
$container.appendChild($image);

var group = document.createElement("div");
group.className = "lz-nav";
$container.appendChild(group);

tmp = document.createElement("a");
tmp.className = "lz-prev";
tmp.onclick = function ()
{
    lzChangeImage(currentImageIndex + 1);
    return false;
};
group.appendChild(tmp);

tmp = document.createElement("a");
tmp.className = "lz-next";
tmp.onclick = function ()
{
    lzChangeImage(currentImageIndex - 1);
    return false;
};
group.appendChild(tmp);

group = document.createElement("div");
group.className = "lz-buttonContainer";
$container.appendChild(group);

tmp = document.createElement("a");
tmp.className = "lz-button lz-more";
tmp.onclick = function ()
{
    if (getElementsByClassName($container, "lz-desc")[0].style.display == 'none')     getElementsByClassName($container, "lz-desc")[0].style.display = '';
    else getElementsByClassName($container, "lz-desc")[0].style.display = 'none';
    return false;
};
group.appendChild(tmp);

tmp = document.createElement("a");
tmp.className = "lz-button lz-print";
tmp.onclick = lzPrint;
group.appendChild(tmp);

tmp = document.createElement("a");
tmp.className = "lz-button lz-download";
tmp.onclick = lzDownload;
tmp.target = "_blank";
group.appendChild(tmp);

tmp = document.createElement("a");
tmp.className = "lz-button lz-buy";
tmp.onclick = lzBuy;
group.appendChild(tmp);

tmp = document.createElement("a");
tmp.className = "lz-button lz-like";
tmp.onclick = lzLike;
group.appendChild(tmp);



//Buttons
if (p != 4) pfx = false;
else
{
    tmp = document.createElement("div");
    tmp.className = "lz-button lz-fullScreen";
    tmp.onclick = function ()
    {
        if (isfull) document[pfx[0]]();
        else $lightzap[pfx[1]]();
    };
    group.appendChild(tmp);
}

tmp = document.createElement("a");
tmp.className = "lz-button lz-close";
tmp.onclick = lzEnd;
group.appendChild(tmp);

$lbContainer = document.createElement("div");
$lbContainer.className = "lz-labelContainer";
$container.appendChild($lbContainer);

tmp = document.createElement("div");
tmp.className = "lz-float lz-caption";
$lbContainer.appendChild(tmp);

tmp = document.createElement("div");
tmp.className = "lz-float lz-desc";
tmp.style.display = 'none';
$lbContainer.appendChild(tmp);

tmp = document.createElement("div");
tmp.className = "lz-float lz-resolution";
$lbContainer.appendChild(tmp);

tmp = document.createElement("a");
tmp.className = "lz-float lz-by";
tmp.target = "_blank";
$lbContainer.appendChild(tmp);

tmp = document.createElement("div");
tmp.className = "lz-float lz-number";
$lbContainer.appendChild(tmp);
};
window.onload = lzInit;

function lzStart($link)
{
//Show overlay
lzShowOthers(false);
lzSizeOverlay();
$lightzap.style.display = '';
$container.style.display = '';
window.onresize = lzSizeOverlay;

//Get original margin
if (marginWidth == -1)
{
    imgNotFound = window.getComputedStyle($image, "").getPropertyValue("background-image").replace("url(", "").replace(")", "").replace('"', '').replace('"', '');
    $image.style.backgroundImage = "none";
    var tmp = window.getComputedStyle($container, "");
    marginHeight = parseInt(tmp.getPropertyValue("margin-top")) + parseInt(tmp.getPropertyValue("margin-bottom")) + parseInt(tmp.getPropertyValue("padding-top")) + parseInt(tmp.getPropertyValue("padding-bottom")) + parseInt(tmp.getPropertyValue("border-top-width")) + parseInt(tmp.getPropertyValue("border-bottom-width"));
    marginWidth = parseInt(tmp.getPropertyValue("margin-left")) + parseInt(tmp.getPropertyValue("margin-right")) + parseInt(tmp.getPropertyValue("padding-left")) + parseInt(tmp.getPropertyValue("padding-right")) + parseInt(tmp.getPropertyValue("border-left-width")) + parseInt(tmp.getPropertyValue("border-right-width"));       
}

//Create album
album = [];
var a, i, _len, _ref, imageNumber = 0;
if ($link.getAttribute("data-lightzap") == "")
    lzReadAlbum($link);
else
{
    var _ref = document.links, _href = $link.href, _attr = $link.getAttribute("data-lightzap"), i = _ref.length, j = 0;
    while (i--)
    {
        var a = _ref[i];
        if (a.getAttribute("data-lightzap") != null && a.getAttribute("data-lightzap") == _attr)
        {
            lzReadAlbum(a);
            if (a.href == $link.href) imageNumber = j;
            j++;
        }
    }
}
lzChangeImage(imageNumber);
return false;
};

function lzReadAlbum($link)
{
var download = false, like = false, buy = false, print = false, options = $link.getAttribute("data-options");
if (options != null && options.length > 4)
{
    download = options.indexOf("download") != -1;
    buy = options.indexOf("buy") != -1;
    like = options.indexOf("like") != -1;

    print = options.indexOf("print") != -1;
}
album.push({
    link: $link.getAttribute("href"),
    title: $link.getAttribute("title"),
    desc: $link.getAttribute("data-desc"),
    by: $link.getAttribute("data-by"),
    by_link: $link.getAttribute("data-link"),
    download: download,
    buy: buy,
    like: like,
    print: print
});
};

function lzChangeImage(imageNumber)
{
//Hide other
document.onkeypress = lzKeyboardAction;
getElementsByClassName($container, "lz-loader")[0].style.display = "";
getElementsByClassName($container, "lz-nav")[0].style.display = "none";
getElementsByClassName($container, "lz-buttonContainer")[0].style.display = "none";
$lbContainer.style.display = "none";
$image.className = "lz-hide";

//New image
var preloader = new Image;
preloader.onload = function ()
{
    $image.src = album[imageNumber].link;
    originalWidth = preloader.width;
    originalHeight = preloader.height;
    currentImageIndex = imageNumber;
    return lzGetImageSize();
};
preloader.onerror = function ()
{
    album[imageNumber].title = notfoundtext;
    album[imageNumber].link = imgNotFound;
    $image.src = album[imageNumber].link;
    originalWidth = 256;
    originalHeight = 256;
    currentImageIndex = imageNumber;
    return lzGetImageSize();
};
preloader.src = album[imageNumber].link;
};

function lzSizeOverlay()
{
var _windowWidth, _windowHeight;
if(typeof(window.innerWidth) == 'number') //Non-IE
{
    _windowWidth = Math.min(window.innerWidth, document.body.clientWidth);
    _windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
}
else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
{
    _windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    _windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
}
else if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) //IE 4 compatible
{
    _windowWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    _windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
}

//If chanced size
if (windowWidth != _windowWidth || windowHeight != _windowHeight)
{
    //Set size
    windowWidth = _windowWidth;//(_windowWidth <= screen.width) ? _windowWidth : screen.width * 0.8;
    windowHeight = _windowHeight;//(_windowHeight <= screen.height) ? _windowHeight : screen.height * 0.8;
    $lightzap.style.width = _windowWidth;
    $lightzap.style.height = _windowHeight;

    //Is fullscreen?
    isfull = false;
    if (pfx != false) isfull = (typeof document[pfx[2]] == "function" ? document[pfx[2]]() : document[pfx[2]]);

    if (!isfull) isfull = (windowWidth >= screen.width * 0.99 && windowHeight >= screen.height * 0.99);

    //Set style
    if (isfull)
    {
        $lightzap.className = "full-screen";
        $lightzap.style.width = "";
        $lightzap.style.height = "";
        $container.style.height = "100%";
        getElementsByClassName($lightzap, "lz-bg")[0].onclick = null;
    }
    else
    {
        getElementsByClassName($lightzap, "lz-bg")[0].onclick = lzEnd
        $lightzap.className = "";
        $container.style.width = "";
        $container.style.height = "";
    }

    //Update image size
    if (album.length > 0)
        lzGetImageSize();
}
};

function lzGetImageSize()
{
//Sizes
var placeWidth = windowWidth, placeHeight = windowHeight, imageWidth = originalWidth, imageHeight = originalHeight;
var master = $container.style, slave = $image.style;
if (!isfull)
{
    placeWidth -= marginWidth;
    placeHeight -= marginHeight;
}
else
{
    slave = master;
    master = $image.style;
    if (pfx)
    {
        placeWidth = screen.width;
        placeHeight = screen.height;
    }
}

//Calculate optional size
if (imageWidth > placeWidth)
{
    imageHeight = (placeWidth * imageHeight) / imageWidth;
    imageWidth = placeWidth;
}
if (imageHeight > placeHeight)
{
    imageWidth = (placeHeight * imageWidth) / imageHeight;
    imageHeight = placeHeight;
}

//Set box style
slave.top = "0";
slave.left = "0";
slave.width = "";
slave.height = "";
master.top = (placeHeight - imageHeight) * 0.5 + "px";
master.left = (placeWidth - imageWidth) * 0.5 + "px";
master.width = imageWidth + "px";
master.height = imageHeight + "px";
lzShowImage();
};

function lzShowImage()
{
lzUpdateNav();
lzUpdateDetails();

//Preload
var preloadNext, preloadPrev;
if (album.length > currentImageIndex + 1)
{
    preloadNext = new Image;
    preloadNext.src = album[currentImageIndex + 1].link;
}
if (currentImageIndex > 0)
{
    preloadPrev = new Image;
    preloadPrev.src = album[currentImageIndex - 1].link;
}

setTimeout(function(){
    $image.className = "lz-image";
    getElementsByClassName($container, "lz-nav")[0].style.display = "";
    $lbContainer.style.display = "";
    getElementsByClassName($container, "lz-buttonContainer")[0].style.display = "";
    getElementsByClassName($container, "lz-loader")[0].style.display = "none";
},380);
};

function lzUpdateDetails()
{
//Counter
var element = getElementsByClassName($lbContainer, "lz-number")[0];
if (album.length > 1)
{
    element.textContent = imagetext + (album.length - currentImageIndex) + oftext + album.length;
    element.style.display = "";
}
else element.style.display = "none";

//Caption
element = getElementsByClassName($lbContainer, "lz-caption")[0];
if (album[currentImageIndex].title != null && album[currentImageIndex].title != "")
{
    element.textContent = album[currentImageIndex].title;
    element.style.display = "";
    if (album[currentImageIndex].title == notfoundtext) return false;
}
else element.style.display = "none";

//Description
element = getElementsByClassName($container, "lz-more")[0];
if (album[currentImageIndex].desc != null && album[currentImageIndex].desc != "")
{
    element.style.display = "";
    element = getElementsByClassName($lbContainer, "lz-desc")[0];
    element.innerHTML = album[currentImageIndex].desc;
    element.style.display = "none";
}
else
{
    element.style.display = "none";
    getElementsByClassName($lbContainer, "lz-desc")[0].style.display = "none";
}

//Author
element = getElementsByClassName($lbContainer, "lz-by")[0];
if (album[currentImageIndex].by != null && album[currentImageIndex].by != "")
{
    element.innerHTML = bytext + " <span>" + album[currentImageIndex].by + "</span>";
    element.style.display = "";
    if (album[currentImageIndex].by_link != null && album[currentImageIndex].by_link != "") element.href = album[currentImageIndex].by_link;
}
else
{
    element.innerHTML = "";
    element.style.display = "none";
    if (album[currentImageIndex].by_link != null && album[currentImageIndex].by_link != "") getElementsByClassName($container, ".lz-caption").html() + '</a>';
}

//Others
getElementsByClassName($container, "lz-like")[0].style.display = (album[currentImageIndex].like != like) ? "" : "none";
getElementsByClassName($container, "lz-buy")[0].style.display = (album[currentImageIndex].buy != buy) ? "" : "none";
getElementsByClassName($container, "lz-download")[0].style.display = (album[currentImageIndex].download != download) ? "" : "none";
getElementsByClassName($container, "lz-print")[0].style.display = (album[currentImageIndex].print != print) ? "" : "none";

getElementsByClassName($lbContainer, "lz-resolution")[0].textContent = originalWidth + " x " + originalHeight;
};

function lzUpdateNav()
{
getElementsByClassName($container, "lz-prev")[0].style.display = "none";
getElementsByClassName($container, "lz-next")[0].style.display = "none";
if (currentImageIndex > 0) getElementsByClassName($container, "lz-next")[0].style.display = "";

if (currentImageIndex < album.length - 1) getElementsByClassName($container, "lz-prev")[0].style.display = "";
};

function lzKeyboardAction(e)
{
var keycode = e.keyCode, key = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode).toLowerCase(),
    KEYCODE_ESC = 27,
    KEYCODE_LEFTARROW = 37,
    KEYCODE_RIGHTARROW = 39,
    KEYCODE_F11 = 122;
if (keycode == KEYCODE_ESC || key.match(/x|o|c/)) lzEnd();
else if (key == "n" || keycode == KEYCODE_RIGHTARROW)
{
    if (currentImageIndex != 0) lzChangeImage(currentImageIndex - 1);
}
else if ((key == "p" || keycode == KEYCODE_LEFTARROW) && currentImageIndex != album.length - 1) lzChangeImage(currentImageIndex + 1);
};

function lzPrint()
{
win = window.open();
self.focus();
win.document.open();
win.document.write("<html><body stlye='margin:0 auto;padding:0;'><h1 style='margin:0 0 0.48em;'>" + getElementsByClassName($container, "lz-caption")[0].textContent + "</h1><div style='text-align:center;'><img src='" + album[lz.currentImageIndex].link + "' style='max-width:100%;max-height:100%;'/></div><div style='text-align:right;'><i>" + getElementsByClassName($container, "lz-by")[0].textContent + "</i></div></body></html>");
win.document.close();
win.print();
win.close();
};

function lzLike()
{
if (!window.focus) return true;
    window.open("http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + $image.src, "", 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes');
};

function lzBuy()
{
if (!window.focus) return true;
window.open("../shop.html",'_self');
};

function lzDownload()
{
if (window.webkitURL)
{ //Webkit
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", album[currentImageIndex].link);
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = (window.URL) ? window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response) : window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
        a.download = album[currentImageIndex].link.substring(album[currentImageIndex].link.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        e.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        a.dispatchEvent(e);
    };
    xhr.send();
    return true;
}
else if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
{ //IE
    win = window.open(album[currentImageIndex].link);
    self.focus();
    win.document.execCommand("SaveAs");
    win.close();
    return true;
}
else
{ //Opera & Firefox (CANVAS)
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    if (typeof canvas.getContext != "undefined")
    {
        try
        {
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvas.width = Math.min(originalWidth, 1024);
            canvas.height = Math.min(originalHeight, originalHeight / originalWidth * 1024);
            canvas.style.width = canvas.width + "px";
            canvas.style.height = canvas.height + "px";
            context.drawImage($image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            document.location.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
            document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            return true;
        }
        catch (err)
        {
            document.body.removeChild(canvas);
        }
    }
}
alert("Sorry, can't download");
};

function lzEnd()
{
if (isfull && pfx != false) document[pfx[0]]();
album = [];
document.onkeypress = null;
window.onresize = null;
$lightzap.style.display = 'none';
$container.style.display = 'none';
lzShowOthers(true);
return false;
};

function lzShowOthers(show)
{
var _ref, i, tagNames = ["select", "object", "embeds"], tagNum = 3;
show = (show) ? "visible" : "hidden";
while(tagNum--)
{
    _ref = document.getElementsByTagName(tagNames[tagNum]);
    i = _ref.length;
    while (i--)
        _ref[i].style.visibility = show;
}
}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself. If anyone will need it in the future here is how I did it:

- Javascript that lets the page to load and starts after 100ms (let
  lightZAP create itself first).
- Get and save hash element.
- Create an if statement: If website has a hash (ex: index.html#img) start lightZAP with element id hash

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function(){
  var hash = window.location.hash.split('#')[1];
  if (window.location.hash != "" ) {
  lzStart(document.getElementById(hash));
  }}, 100);
  ```

Also, when defining images that are required to be displayed by lightZAP it is necessary to add a few lines:

- a tag is suppose to have rel="lightzap" and id="img"

Example:

```
<div class="single first"><a rel="lightzap" id="a1" gref="../images/Alaska/a1.jpg" data-lightzap="Alaska" data-desc = "desc" title="Alaska"> <img src="../images/Alaska/a1-thumb.jpg"> </a> </div>
```